# How to associate a unique integer to a matrix with integer elements in $[-1 , 100]$

Tags: matrices, hash-function

I have a $n \times m$ matrix $A$ with entries $A_{i,j} \in [0 , 100] \cap \mathbb{Z}$. with a great likelihood of 0

I would like to represent this matrix by the smallest integer value possible.

What would be the best way to do so?

EDIT:  The bottom line is to represent matrices into an integer so that they could be "easily" compared by a computer to find duplicate.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well you could always try positional representations of the elements...

Comment: 1) Do you mean $A_{i,j} \in [-1,100]$ ? 2) Could you explain what you mean by "representing  by the smallest integer value"  using for example a low dimension example ?

Comment: Is it a data compression issue ?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : Sure, but since we don't want any -1 nor 0 in this solution, I'll have to add 2 to each value, that would then give me a value \in [N*M, 103^(N*M)]... with N and M being 16 and 100, the value would be off the chart...

Comment: @JeanMarie : No, data compression is not an issue

Comment: @JeanMarie 1) yes Ai,j∈[−1,100]. I need to issue an integer less that 2^32 would be nice

Comment: @mvw : yes. Ai,j∈ [−1,100]

Comment: @mvw : Unicity is indeed the issue here. The bottom line is to represent matrices into an integer so that they could be easily compared by a computer and duplicate removed.

Comment: I fear it is impossible ubing only 32 bits. If $m \times n>5$, as you need $\approx 6.5$ bits per entry, the number of bits is $ > 5 \times 6.5 \approx 32$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: 1) thanks. 2) my bad, I meant 2^(8*32) as the max size, but it can also be 2^(64*8) or more.. I just need the smallest... 3) as far as compression goes, come to think of it, -1 are unimportant, so Ai,j∈[0,100]∩ℤ with a great likelihood of 0.

Comment: If your matrix is *sparse* (say above 90% of zeros), there are specific (efficient) representations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

Comment: I read again your question: a better presentation would be: "How to find a bijective encoding of these matrices with integers in $[0,2^{8 \times 32}]$ in order to be able to retrieve and compare easily two of them."

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer is to hash the file.  Unless you have a *lot* of matrices, the chance  of a collision is very small.  You just have to have a well defined way of representing the matrix, always with the same number of spaces between the entries for example.  Then you can compare the hashes.  If you insist, you can go back to the original files whenever the hashes match and do a real compare to avoid collisions.